# How can I use Color box jQuery plugin For direct <img> elements?

Tags: jquery, colorbox, image-gallery

I've created a media gallery where I want to show the images with a **[colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)**. 
The HTML structure that I try to use colorbox on it, is like below:

```
<div class="image-gallary">
  <img src="/patch_to_image/image_1.png">
  <img src="/patch_to_image/image_2.png">
  <img src="/patch_to_image/image_3.png">
  <img src="/patch_to_image/image_4.png">
</div>
```

and jQuery intialazation is:

```
  $('div.image-gallary>img').colorbox({
    rel:'images',
    transition:"fade",
    opacity:0.5 ,
    rel:'group1'
  });
```

When I click on images the clorbox load and popup's show up but images not load (not display, still loading image).

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because Colorbox depends on the `href` attribute on the anchor element in order to load the page correctly. The easy solution is to simply wrap each `<img src="/path/to/image">` element with a corresponding `<a href="/path/to/image">`, and you are good to go.

The reasoning behind this is simple: from a UI perspective, **the images are meant to be clicked on, so intuitively they should be wrapped in an interactable element** (`<a>` will be your to-go element). Imagine if JS does not work on the page: that will mean that the images remain clickable ;) that is good UI!

```js
$(function() {
  $('div.image-gallary>a').colorbox({
    rel: 'images',
    transition: "fade",
    opacity: 0.5,
    rel: 'group1'
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.colorbox/1.6.4/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>

<div class="image-gallary">
  <a href="http://i.imgur.com/YzuqChn.gif"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/YzuqChn.gif"></a>
  <a href="http://i.imgur.com/Am3foce.gif"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Am3foce.gif"></a>
</div>
```

If you do not want to modify the markup, there is an alternative solution: you can simply use the `href` option of the plugin to specify the URL. Note that in this case, you will need to iterate through all the images (instead of passing a collection to the `.colorbox()` method, because you will need pointers to each of their `src` attribute individually:

```js
$(function() {
  $('div.image-gallary>img').each(function() {
    // Iterate through individual images...
    // because we need access to their 'src' attribute
    $(this).colorbox({
      rel: 'images',
      transition: "fade",
      opacity: 0.5,
      rel: 'group1',
      href: $(this).attr('src')
    });
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.colorbox/1.6.4/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>

<div class="image-gallary">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/YzuqChn.gif" />
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Am3foce.gif" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, But I can't change my 'CMS' auto generated the dom structure.

Comment: See my updated comment. Also... your CMS should allow basic modification of markup, e.g. adding a link.